How to obtain gpio number for irq number defined in the device tree
irq_to_gpio() is being removed and should not be available anymore.
Device tree:
interrupts = <GIC_SPI 14 IRQ_TYPE_EDGE_BOTH>;

The IRQ number assigned by the platform is 56.
Is there any valid contemporary method to get gpio pin number (14) in the linux kernel module? I can of course define it in gpios section, but that must duplicate the info machine already has.

If you know it's the 2nd u32 value in the property, you could read it with rc = of_property_read_u32_index(np, "interrupts", 1, &gpionum);.

@IanAbbott this may be an option in this case when you know how device tree is laid out in this platform, but that may not be portable. Not sure why this irq_to_gpio was removed at all. I tried to put it in and while it is still in header files compiler does not find it.

Sure it's not portable. rc = of_irq_parse_one(np, 0, &oarg); would be slightly better, although it also relies on the layout. It gives you a phandle for the interrupt controller, and its list of arguments.

That's sh*t. I would better define the gpio number in the interrupt-gpios section of the device tree.

It's not as if irq_to_gpio() was ever portable in the first place. Most implementations just returned -EINVAL.

One shouldn’t need this. Your question lacks of the details why you ask for this.

@IanAbbott, regarding to your first comment, it’s not how retrieval if the resource from DT should be done in properly written code in Linux, and TBH I am badly surprised you even gave such a comment…

@0andriy I did not know that OP was striving for portability at the time.

follow these steps .
step 1 - Identify the GPIO Controller: Locate the GPIO controller in the Device Tree. It’s typically defined in a node with gpio-controller.
step 2 -Identify the IRQ Mapping: Locate the device node that specifies the IRQ number, usually found in the interrupts property.
step 3 - Translate IRQ to GPIO: Utilize the Linux kernel's GPIO and IRQ APIs to convert the IRQ number to the corresponding GPIO number.

please elaborate on item 3. how exactly do you propose doing it?
